# Take the positive part of values in a matrix in R

Tags: r

I have 2 vectors `z`, `v`and I want to find the value of (z- v)_{+} which + means that if z bigger than v put it equal to z-v and else is zero.

```
      z = c(0.00000000, 0.00000000, 0.05626874, 0.17529181, 0.25865020, 0.27993760,
     0.52217908, 0.85310551, 1.13850492, 2.08570299)
     v= c( 0.00000000, 0.05626874, 0.07096722, 0.17529181, 0.17574861, 0.25865020,
     0.27993760, 0.28331125, 0.34191489, 0.52217908, 0.56703446, 0.67147343,
     0.85310551, 1.00063564, 1.13850492, 1.24488131, 1.36113151, 2.08570299,4.12977829)
```

I can create the matrix of mat1 , but I want to put (z_ij - v_ij) instead of true and else equal to zero. How can I do this in R?

```
   mat1 = sapply(1:length(v), function(i) outer(z, v[i], ">"))
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Okay, this just shows both steps, with an alternate way of taking the positive part:

```
d <- outer(z,v,"-")
d <- d*(d>0)
```

Oh, the other version of the second line (in a removed answer) was: `d[d<0] <- 0`.